# StartPreviewAsync with CaptureElement in MVVM UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, camera, uwp

I'm working for camera with MVVM by Prism app and use this method to show the preview in CaptureElement component

```
private async Task StartPreviewAsync(string deviceId)
        {
            try
            {
                _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
                MediaCaptureInitializationSettings setting = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
                setting.VideoDeviceId = deviceId;
                await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(setting);
                //_displayRequest.RequestActive();
                //DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape;
                CaptureElementSource = _mediaCapture;
                //This line throw exception
                await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("The app was denied access to the camera");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("MediaCapture initialization failed. {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

This is my CaptureElement.Source prop:

```
public MediaCapture CaptureElementSource
        {
            get { return _captureElementSouce; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _captureElementSouce, value); }
        }
```

And I'm getting this exception:

```
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Mateo.UILogic.ViewModels.CameraSelectionPageViewModel.<StartPreviewAsync>d__111.MoveNext()
```

> An unexpected error has occurred in the operation requested. Preview
>   sink not set

Anyone, please help me in this.

Comment: Just curious, why you put `MediaCapture` in your view model? I don't think `MediaCapture` belongs to view model.

Comment: @Scavenger I tried every way but MediaCapture just run in its Dispatcher, which only exist in code behind. So I wrote my code on code behind already. :D Like what u said, mediacapture not belong to VM

Answer (score 0):

I just got this same error when I forgot to check the WebCam and Microphone options in the Package.appxManifst -> Capabilities section.